# OSX Fuse/SSHFS will not auto mount from /etc/fstab on mac (but sudo mount -a works!)

Tags: osx-yosemite, fstab, sshfs

I have recently installed OS X Fuse and SSHFS on my mac, and I can mount my sshfs manually with `sudo mount -a` but I would really like it to mount automatically, given the contents of my `/etc/fstab`

The fact that `sudo mount -a` works, makes me think that the actual `/etc/fstab` is okay.

I've also done the thing which is mentioned 'around the web' where I have added the sysctl `allow_other=1` thingy to my startup items, and can confirm that the sysctl property is reporting `allow_other=1` after reboot... But my fstab is still not read and mounted correctly!

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.3
BuildVersion:   14D136
```